# permission_classes doesn't work . where is problem?

Tags: permissions, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to found how Restframework's permission work , so i try write some code that response a simple Json. But the existence or absence of a ‍`permission_classes` does not affect the execution of the code and endpoint will response all request without checking any permission.

here is my code:

```
class TeacherStatisticPost(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (ClassOwnerPermission)
    queryset = ClassRoom.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'classRoom_id'

    def get_klass(self):
        class_id = self.kwargs['classRoom_id']
        return ClassRoom.objects.get(id=classRoom_id)

    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        klass = self.get_klass()
        response ={
             'class_room_grade' : klass.grade,
              'class_room_name' : klass.name,
             }
        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

and here is my permission.py:

```
class ClassOwnerPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_perm(self, user, klass):
        print("now in class perm") # never print out any thing!
        return klass.owner == user

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj): # where is come from 'obj' ?
        return self.has_perm(request.user, obj)
```

im try to set permission that just owner of ClassRoom can access to this endpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, DRF expects `permission_classes` to be list or tuple. `permission_classes` at the line `permission_classes = (ClassOwnerPermission)`  is not neither tuple not list. Put comma after the `ClassOwnerPermission`.

The line `permission_classes = (ClassOwnerPermission, )`  should work.

Secondly, you do not use `get_object` method which checks the permissions. Remove `def get_klass(self):` method and use [get_object](http://www.cdrf.co/3.3/rest_framework.generics/RetrieveAPIView.html#get_object)

Your view should look like following:

```py
class TeacherStatisticPost(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (ClassOwnerPermission, )
    queryset = ClassRoom.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "id"
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'classRoom_id'

    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        klass = self.get_object()
        response ={
             'class_room_grade' : klass.grade,
              'class_room_name' : klass.name,
             }
        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

Comment: thank you . helped so much , im trying for 3 days for this `self.get_object` . can i ask another question sir? what is the best class that is better to used in above code ?APIView or ViewSet or ... ?and idea to can write my goal better? thank you again

Comment: @mehdi you use `ViewSet` when you're doing `fetch`, `update`, `delete`, `partial update` etc basically many sets of operations from one view. If your requirement is just to get the details of particular object use `RetrieveView`. If you want something very basic and customised which is not provided by default views use `APIView`, similarly there are other views, they can be used in combinations.